# Virtual box error: "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted."

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtualbox, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VirtualBox Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted](https://superuser.com/questions/69202/virtualbox-fatal-no-bootable-medium-found-system-halted)

This question has been asked few times before, but I am not able to find the answer. I had downloaded the `.iso` image of Linux Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 (size of the image: 711,980 KB). I already had a virtual machine for Ubuntu 9.10 working in my Windows XP system; but don't know what is the problem here.

I gave following configuration:

```
Base Memory (RAM): 1500 MB
Boot Order: Floppy, CD/DVD ROM, Hard disk
Video Memory: 12 MB
IDE Secondary Master: VBoxGuestAdditions.iso (32 MB)
Storage size: 25 GB (dynamically expandable)
```

Other details:

```
vdi file location: D:\VirtualMachine_Harddisks\Ubuntu_Oneiric\Linux_Ubuntu_Oneiric.vdi
iso image location: D:\Ubuntu\ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

I have no idea what is going wrong ? Any inputs will be highly appreciated.